# Terraform AWS CloudWatch log group for ECS tasks/containers

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create an AWS ECS task with Terraform which will put logs in a specific log group on CloudWatch. The problem is that container definition is in the JSON file and there is no way for me to map the CloudWatch group name from .tf file to that .json file.

container_definition.json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "supreme-task",
    "image": "xxxx50690yyyy.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/supreme-task",
    "essential": true,
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 5000,
        "hostPort": 5000
      }
    ],
    "logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
        "awslogs-group": "supreme-task-group",  <- This needs to be taken from variable.tf file.
        "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "streaming"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

variable.tf:

```
variable "ecs_task_definition_name" {
  description = "Task definition name."
  type = string
  default = "supreme-task-def"
}

variable "task_role" {
  description = "Name of the task role."
  type = string
  default = "supreme-task-role"
}

variable "task_execution_role" {
  description = "Name of the task execution role."
  type = string
  default = "supreme-task-exec-role"
}

variable "cloudwatch_group" {
  description = "CloudWatch group name."
  type = string
  default = "supreme-task-group"
}
```

task definition:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_definition" {
  family = var.ecs_task_definition_name
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode = "awsvpc"
  cpu = 1024
  memory = 4096
  container_definitions = file("modules/ecs-supreme-task/task-definition.json")
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.task_execution_role.name
  task_role_arn = aws_iam_role.task_role.name
}
```

Is there a way to do that? Or maybe this should be done differently?

Comment: Have you tried either interpolation (by having the JSON inline in a HEREDOC) or using the templating features of Terraform?

Comment: Interpolation with inline JSON worked, thanks! :)

Comment: Did you want to self answer it?

Comment: No need, you can do it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Solved by following @ydaetskcorR's comment.

Made container definition as inline parameter.

```
container_definitions = <<DEFINITION
    [
      {
        "name": "${var.repository_name}",
        "image": "${var.repository_uri}",
        "essential": true,
        "portMappings": [
          {
            "containerPort": 5000,
            "hostPort": 5000
          }
        ],
        "logConfiguration": {
          "logDriver": "awslogs",
          "options": {
            "awslogs-group": "${var.cloudwatch_group}",
            "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
            "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
    DEFINITION
```

Comment: tried this but dint work for me  ECS Task Definition container_definitions is invalid: Error decoding JSON: invalid character '"' after object key:value pair

Comment: This was two years ago, it's possible that terraform's API has changed.

Comment: TF requires to get the string encoded in json I bealieve, the first line should be `container_definitions = jsonencode([` without heredoc ( `<<DEFINITION`)

Comment: it worked perfectly in terraform v1.6.2. I dont kno why but the same configuration using jsonencode didnt work for me

Answer (score 5):

If you want to load the container definition as a template to avoid inlining the content in the tf files, then you could:

1- Create the container definition as a template file with variables, just note that the extension would be .tpl

container_definition.tpl

```
[
  {
    "name": "supreme-task",
    "image": "xxxx50690yyyy.dkr.ecr.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/supreme-task",
    "essential": true,
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "containerPort": 5000,
        "hostPort": 5000
      }
    ],
    "logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
        "awslogs-group": "${cloudwatch_group}",
        "awslogs-region": "eu-central-1",
        "awslogs-stream-prefix": "streaming"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

2- Then load the file as a template an inject the variables:

task_definition.tf

```
data template_file task_definition {
  template = file("${path.module}/container_definition.tpl")

  vars = {
    cloudwatch_group = var.cloudwatch_group
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "task_definition" {
  family = var.ecs_task_definition_name
  requires_compatibilities = ["FARGATE"]
  network_mode = "awsvpc"
  cpu = 1024
  memory = 4096
  container_definitions = data.template_file.task_definition.rendered
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.task_execution_role.name
  task_role_arn = aws_iam_role.task_role.name
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this in terraform -

```
# Container definition
    container_definitions = jsonencode([
        {
            name                    = "app-container-test"
            image                   = "acc_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/repository-test:4"
            cpu                     = 256
            memory                  = 512
            port_mappings = [
                {
                    container_port  = 80
                    host_port       = 80
                    protocol        = "tcp"
                }
            ]
            logConfiguration = {
            logDriver = "awslogs"
            options   = {
                "awslogs-group"         = "fargate-logs-test"
                "awslogs-region"        = var.aws_region
                "awslogs-stream-prefix" = "ecs"
            }
        }
        }
```

> don't forget add logs permission (role, policy)